# Remove issn/doi/url when using plainnat and natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am using `natbib` and the `plainnat` style for the references. I would like to know how can I remove the ISSN, DOI and URL from the references without deleting them in the .bib file. I have seen some solutions in other posts but using `biblatex`; is there any solution for using `natbib`?

This is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\author{Me}
\title{Article}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    This article...
\end{abstract}
\section{Intro}
    According to \citet{John2003} ...
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibl}
\end{document}
```

`bibl` contains an entry with the keycode John2003

Comment: Look for FUNCTION {format.url} in .bst file, then remove all text between the curly braces, e.g. FUNCTION {format.url} { url empty$ { "" } { "" } if$ }

Answer (score 43):

I would not recommend modifying the `*.bib` file. You may need these fields one day (some journals ask to put DOI/ISSN, and URLs can be useful for your own reference). Instead, you should change the *style* file that regulates how bibliography is displayed.

Locate `plainnat.bst` file on your computer. Copy it to the directory with your `*.tex` files, rename it to something like `plainnatnourl.bst` and modify it such that it does not print URLs. You can then use

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnatnourl}
```

Modification should be rather simple. In case of `abbrvnat.bst` the only thing I had to do was to change

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { <SOME CODE THAT FORMATS URL> }
  if$
}
```

to

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { "" }
  if$
}
```

`plainnat.bst` should be similar.

Comment: Worked like a charm: to get rid of the annoying "URL" label I just did a case-sensitive search for "URL" in the copied/renamed .bst file using my text editor then manually deleted "URL ".

Comment: Since both branches of the `if$` now do the same, we can shorten things a bit to `FUNCTION {format.url} { "" }`

Answer (score 13):

Don't delete, just rename the key, i.e. `ISSN -> OPTISSN`. Then the data is still there but is ignored by bibtex as it does not know `OPTISSN`

Comment: And how can I rename the key?

Comment: How do you normally edit your `.bib` file?

Comment: I use the JabRef program.

Comment: Hmm, no idea. I usually edit using a normal text editor. I just installed JabRef, it does not seem to be able to rename a key. You should be able to make a copy of your `.bib` file, open the copy in your normal LaTeX editor (perhaps unless it is `LyX`) and then do a search'n'replace using the LaTeX editor. A `.bib` file *is* just text. JabRef just diesplays it in a convenient manner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works, but it is quite a tedious work, at least in my case because I have several `.bib` files. I will use this solution in a precise moment, but I would like to know if there is any other solution to my problem.

Comment: Most `bibtex` style files are not configurable, so alas.

Comment: Brilliantly simple solution!

Comment: It's a useless hack and barley generalizable. Nowadays most .bib files in use are generated automatically (JabRef, Mendeley, etc.)

Comment: @MERose no, it is a useless feature in those programmes that one cannot rename a key

Answer (score 9):

You can remove fields if you use biblatex, use this in your preamble (remove `\usepackage[square,sort&compress,comma,numbers]{natbib}`)

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{issn} % Remove issn
  \clearfield{doi} % Remove doi

  \ifentrytype{online}{}{% Remove url except for @online
    \clearfield{url}
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should add that you need to use `biber` not `bibtex` for this to work...

Comment: for me it works with biblatex

Comment: doesn't work in overleaf

Answer (score 8):

It's easy to create your own bst-file using the custom-bib package. You run

```
latex makebst
```

This will start a series of question to which you respond y (yes) or n (no), and at the end it will create a bst-file for you. The questions include if DOI/URL fields should be included in bibliography.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with varepsilon that you can edit the .bst file.
However I would **not** edit the `FUNCTION {format.url}`... because this will mean that the URL will never be displayed...So also not for online resources, where you actually want it!

Instead, I would look for the source-specific style functions, e.g. `FUNCTION {article}`. There just remove the lines with `format.isbn output`, `format.doi output`, and `format.url output`. Do this for every style you don't want to see the ISBN/DOI/URL.

Of course don't do this for `FUNCTION {misc}`, which is used for online resources and such...

Also, remember that journals some times don't like you tinkering with their reference style (even if there are errors in it). You'll have to manage with the style they give you...

Answer (score 4):

You can directly add the options to the `usepackage` directive:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, isbn=false, issn=false, doi=false]{biblatex}
```

Comment: The options you mention are for the biblatex package but the question was about natbib package

Answer (score 1):

I'd liked to post this as a comment. To improve the makeshift of doing search and replace, you can use a tool, such as [textcrawler](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html), to rename entries in several files/directories. It's also possible to filter the files to be searched, e. g. by ending *.bib

Answer (score 1):

According to [this discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/discussion/318825/thread/09ebe6ef/), one can easily open the `*.bib` file using  [JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/), then select `Quality > Set/clear/append/rename fields`.

Then, any field can be chosen for a specific entry or all entries to edit/rename/clear.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the Bibliography style file `plainnat.bst`. If you cannot find this style file in your `tex` directory, you can download it from this [website](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/plainnat.bsthttps://).

Download and rename the style file as `plainnat-modified.bst`. Open the file using a text editor and modify the following lines:

```
FUNCTION {format.isbn}
{ isbn empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "ISBN " isbn * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.issn}
{ issn empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "ISSN " issn * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "URL \url{" url * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

to these

```
FUNCTION {format.isbn}
{ isbn empty$
    { "" }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.issn}
{ issn empty$
    { "" }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { "" }
  if$
}
```

Upload the modified style file to your `tex` folder and change your `LaTeX` code as

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-modified}
```

Done!

Comment: I think this has already been mentioned in the top answer by varepsilon.

Comment: @Roland Yes, but it is more detailed, because it show also the changes for issn and isbn. So maybe it is a kind of improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with bibtex or natbib and creating an individual `.bst`-file or renaming fields in Jabref is not an option, you may want to edit the actual `.bib`-file. In Windows you can use a batch-script for this.
Create a file, e.g. `filterbib.bat` with the following content

```
findstr /V "doi url issn" references.bib  > referencesfiltered.bib
```

Call it and it will create a copy of your `.bib`-file without the unwanted entries, which you can then load in your document.

I wouldn't recommend to modify the original `.bib`-file as you will loose important information. That is why using biblatex or creating a custom style file is still the best option. Unfortunately, only a few journals permit that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the discussion goes the following procedure was pretty helpful.

Select the entries (or all entries using ctrl+A) then go to "Edit"> Manage field names & content. Select url from the drop down box of "Field names". Finally check on " Rename field to "Url_JabRef" and then click "OK".[image]

Answer (score 0):

This not specific to natbib, but you can use [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) with the [Better Bibtex plugin](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/) to [omit specified fields](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/installation/preferences/export/#fields-to-omit-from-export-comma-separated) from its exported bibtex file which will then be used by natbib.

In Zotero (with the Better Bibtex plugin installed) this is configured by going to `Preferences->Better Bibtex->Export->Fields->Fields to omit from export`, and adding a comma separated list of fields to exclude.