# Removing URLs with natbib and Mendeley in Overleaf

Tags: natbib, overleaf, mendeley

I'm using the Mendeley online reference manager, linked to Overleaf with bibtex.

Currently my bibliography entries look like this:

[image]

i.e. there are several URLs all linked together. I don't want any URLs whatsoever in my bibliography - is there a way to implement this?

I've already written my PhD thesis with natbib, so please do not recommend a switch to biblatex.

So far I haven't been able to find a .bst file in Overleaf, as recommended by the top answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125133/remove-issn-doi-url-when-using-plainnat-and-natbib).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Instead of choosing to ignore all `URL` strings, you may want to ask why the entry in question feautures more than one `URL` string to begin with.

Comment: It's because of imperfect Mendeley performance, which is a whole other SO post ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've done it!

I used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553385/where-to-find-apacite-bst-file-to-change-bibliography-style) to get a copy of abbrvnat.bst from the virtual machine.

I then used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125133/remove-issn-doi-url-when-using-plainnat-and-natbib) to modify it such that URLs are not displayed.

I re-uploaded the file to my overleaf home directory as myabbrvnat.bst and called it with \bibliographystyle{myabbrvnat}.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to change `url` to `furl`, rather than hack the .bst file.

Comment: Can you point to any documentation of this approach? I'm struggling to find anything by googling "url furl bibtex latex".

Comment: Instead of `furl`, user @jII could have suggested you rename the field to `burl`, `curl`, `girl`,`hurl`, `pearl`, etc.  The point is that BibTeX does *not* act on fields whose names it's not programmed to recognize. These days, lots and lots of bib styles are programmed to recognize and process a field named `url`. In contrast, to the best of my knowledge, there's not a single bib style that does anything with fields named `burl`, `curl`, `girl` `furl`, `hurl`, `pearl`, etc.

Comment: Oh I see - so the suggestion is to modify the .bib file and change the field from url to *url?

I recognise this is a solution, but quite time consuming to work through several hundred bib entries and implement? Perhaps I have the wrong end of the stick though.

Ideally I would also like to keep the urls but just not display them in this particular doc?

Comment: Robbie, you can use a sed script, or a simple search/replace in your text editor, to do the text processing